# How Scrapy write CSV files in several times

Tags: python, csv, scrapy

I"m using scrapy with python 2.7.9 , my spider can crawl the data normally.

But I found the data is too big,so I want to crawl the data in one spider in several times and write to different CSV files.

For example: Totally ,I have "One hundred and ten thousand " webpages,I want the spider to crawl "30 thousand","30 thousand","30 thousand","20 thousand" respectively.

How can I do? Can I done it only in "spider"? Or maybe in "pipelines" ?

Please somebody help me.

My code link:https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6SUWnrBmDwSWmY1em1vbktyOWc&authuser=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one easy way would be to send `from` and `to` as [spider arguments](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#spider-arguments)

```
scrapy crawl myspider -a from=30001 -a to=60000
```